# Lining up the boxes with negative entries in a Young tableau

Tags: ytableau

Given the partition (5,2), I would like the boxes in the following Young tableau to line up:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[enableskew]{youngtab} 
\begin{document}
$\young({-3}{-2}{-1}01,:23)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

More specifically, the box containing 2 should be below the box containing -2 and the box containing 3 should be below the box containing -1, and I would like the boxes to all have the same size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a different package called `ytableau`, where it seems to be easer to achieve what you want, since the syntax is more "tabular-like". `\none` is used to have no box at the first place of the second line. Set the `boxsize` to a value you like.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ytableau} 
\begin{document}
\ytableausetup{mathmode, boxsize=2em}
\begin{ytableau}
-3 & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1\\
\none & 2 & 3\\
\end{ytableau}
\end{document}
```

[image]